# Creating a multi-step/component form using switch statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a multi step form that upon clicking next and previous switches between four components (at this point I'm not interested in passing any data but just view the pages). I have made the switch case but Now I do not know how to return the first component. I'm following this example with modifications since I'm using the create-react-app : https://github.com/tommymarshall/react-multi-step-form/blob/master/src/javascript/components/Registration.jsx

and here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PageOne from './PageOne';
import PageTwo from './PageTwo';
import PageThree from './PageThree';
import PageFour from './PageFour';

class Form extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      allInputs: []
    }
  }
  componentWillMount () {
    this.setState({allInputs: []})
  }
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      step: 1
    }
  }
  saveValues(input) {
    let allInputs = this.state.allInputs;
    allInputs.push(input);
    this.setState({allInputs:allInputs});
  }
  nextStep() {
    this.setState({
      step: this.state.step +1
    })
  }
  previousStep() {
     this.setState({
       step : this.state.step - 1
     })
  }
  submitRegistration() {this.nextStep()}

  showStep() {
    switch (this.state.step) {
      case 1:
        return <PageOne 
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        previousStep={this.previousStep}
                        saveValues={this.saveValues} />
      case 2:
        return <PageTwo 
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        previousStep={this.previousStep}
                        saveValues={this.saveValues} />
      case 3:
        return <PageThree 
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        previousStep={this.previousStep}
                        saveValues={this.saveValues} />
      case 4:
        return <PageFour 
                        previousStep={this.previousStep}
                        submitRegistration={this.submitRegistration}  />
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Form">
        {this.showStep()} 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Form;
```

At this point I should be seeing the first component rendering

Comment: Remove `getInitialState`, add `step: 1` to your `this.state` object inside of your constructor. The `getInitialState` function is deprecated with ES6 classes and should only be used with `React.createClass`.

Comment: @Dan thank you that did the trick! any suggestions on how to keep track of the steps as I go along?

Comment: Keeping up with documentation and reading blog posts from React (https://reactjs.org/blog) is a great start.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getInitialState()`, add the `step` property inside the constructor itself:

```
constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      allInputs: [],
      step: 1
    }
}
```

Also use functional setState if you are relying on previous state for next state, since [setState is async](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3). Eg: convert your functions like:

```
nextStep() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ step: prevState.step + 1 }))
}
```